# Android Verify login in the remote MySQL

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

Ok. I have a remote mySQL set up and the table have two pair values. Email: aa, password: aa and Email: bb, password: bb.

In my main activity, in the loginOnClickListener, I declare a backgroundworker class which extends the AsyncTask class to do the remote connection and verify the login. If email and password are correct, the value "Success" would return to String result in the onPostExecute(String result). I declare a public static String result in the MainActivity. Inside the onPostExecute(String result) of the backgoundworker class

```
@Override   
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    LoginActivity.get=result;
    delegate.processFinish(result);
    alertDialog.setMessage(result);
    alertDialog.show(); // alertDiaglog can always show the correct message, no "delay"

}
```

In the MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 

    public static String result;




 public void loginButtonListener(){
    button_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String type = "login";
            String email = editText_email.getText().toString();
            String password = editText_password.getText().toString();

            BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker(LoginActivity.this);
            worker.delegate=LoginActivity.this;
            worker.execute(type, email, password);
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,get,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // result is null in the first time
        }
    });

}
```

So the value of result would return to MainActivity and I can verify if the string is "Success" and it will go to another activity once log in success. However, when I first sucessfully log in, the value of String result is null in Mainactivity, and then I entered a wrong password, and the result becomes "Success" and then becomes "Fails".

In general, the value of String result in MainActivity is always one step behind the results generated by the button click because of the first null string. Anybody has a idea how to verify login or how to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you add more code to your question for where in MainActivity you use this `result` value? And is there a LoginActivity or something? Where do you use this AsyncTask?

Comment: I posted it. @cricket_007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I striped down what you are trying to do to a Button and an inner AsyncTask class. Take note that the Toast and starting the new Activity are in the `onPostExecute` because the AsyncTask runs asynchronously, which means, it could return at any point in the future, not immediately after you click the button or call `.execute()`.

I don't have a SQL database to test against, so I just slept the running thread for a second to simulate a network operation.

It's also worth noting that by making the inner class, you can easily call `startActivity` and `finish` because you are still within scope of the current activity `Context`.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String email = "test@test.com"; // blah, blah .getText()
                String password = "password"; // blah, blah .getText()

                new LoginTask().execute("type?", email, password);
            }
        });
    }

    class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        private String email;

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            String type = params[0];
            this.email = params[1]; // save the email, if you want
            String password = params[2];

            // Do your database stuff
            try {
                // Simulate some long running operation
                Thread.sleep(1000L);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(result), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (result) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("email", this.email); // send some arguments to the next activity
                startActivity(i); // You have logged-in, move to the next screen
                finish(); // Kill the login activity
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why I have to finish the login Activity? What if i do not kill that login activity?

Comment: Don't have to. You just don't need it anymore. If you don't then you'll be able to press the back key on the device and it'll probably go back to the login activity because it is on the backstack (where activities are stored). Obviously you shouldn't see the login activity if you are already logged-in.

Comment: Suppose I have a very complicated application and may have 100+ activities, and I do not have finish() in all of them, is that OK? Is that affects the speed of the app?

Comment: Android will start to automatically kill them once it runs out of memory. As you keep starting Activities, they are placed on a stack like a deck of cards. There is a limit to that stack and it makes no sense to keep piling on more cards once it becomes too large.

Comment: Most "complicated" applications probably have at most 10-20 activities, though. Fragments are the recommended method for displaying information.

Comment: so every time I finish doing some stuffs with a activity, I need to finish() it at the end of it in order to save the memory? Is that what your mean? thanks a lot

Comment: Like I said, you don't need/have to. Android will do it on it's own. If you don't need to "go back", though. It is recommended you finish the activity immediately after starting another.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are starting an Async task, which is asynchronous so naturally the value of `result` will be null initially. When `postExecute()` completes, it will assign result to this variable and then you can have its value.

**Update**

Declare an interface like which will have onLoginResult method

```
public interface LoginInterface {

  public void onLoginResult(String result);
}
```

Make your Activity implement this method

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoginInterface {

  @Override
  public void onLoginResult(String result) {

  }



 @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MyAsyncTask task = new MyAsyncTask(this);
}

}
```

Assuming your AsyncTask is MyAsyncTask

```
class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    private LoginInterface loginInterface;

     //Change the number of arguments according to your requirements.
    AsyncTask(LoginInterface loginInterface) {
    this.loginInterface  = loginInterface;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

        // Some code

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        loginInterface.onLoginResult(result);
    }
}
```

Now once `postExecute` complete it will make a call to your MainActivity's `onLoginResult` with the actual result. Here you can do whatever stuff you want like starting an activity.

Comment: I set a Toast inside the onPostExecute() and it can always show the correct message by using the result String but it went wrong when pass it to the MainActivity.

Comment: The time when you are trying to access the result must be before the time you actually get the result. Try putting System.currentTimeMillis() in 2 places 1) where you are trying to access the variable 2) inside postexecute when the value actually comes. You can clearly see that you are trying to access it value before it has come.

Comment: Good adviss! @Anshul Jain. I finally set a timeout before Toasting to wait for the thread to complete and it works!

Comment: @KKKK: putting timeout for testing purpose is fine. shouldn't use it in real scenarios.

Comment: I want to start a new Activity in the onPostExecute() if the login success , but there always errors occurs. I assume that we cannot start a new activity in the onPostExecute() in the AsyncTask ? @cricket_007

Comment: @KKKK: updating my answer on how you can achieve this.

Comment: Might want to fix your code. `interface` is a reserved word

Comment: Welcome. Yeah, I usually do I quick hop into a new Android Studio project when answering these types of questions to make sure I'm typing the right stuff and it all works.

Comment: My Android Studio is busy in gradle sync.. :P . so had to write the code without editor..

Comment: Sorry to hear that. And I used to do the interface callback approach that you showed, but that got messy really quick for a large project.

Comment: yeah. there are some other ways like passing data through Bus. But for a small project and for a beginner this approach would be good I guess.